# In Angular, How to externalize Providers as constants to be exported?

Tags: angular

To get a better file management in my project, I would like to extract providers and put in external files as constant. It's my first experience with providers.
I would like to get this file structure :

```
|- src/
   |- common/
      |- providers/
         |- parent.provider.ts
         ... others providers   
   |- components/
      |- foo.component.ts 
      ... others components
```

### parent.provider.ts

```
// Helper method to provide the current component instance in the name of a `parentType`.
// The `parentType` defaults to `Parent` when omitting the second parameter.
export const provideParent =
    (component: any, parentType ? : any) => {
        return { provide: parentType || Parent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => component) };
    };
```

### foo.component.ts

```
import {provideParent} from '../common/providers/parent.provider';
...
@Component({
    providers:  [ provideParent(FooComponent) ]
})
...
```

For the moment I get this error during the compilation :

> error TS4023: Exported variable 'provideParent' has or is using name 'Type' from external module "path/to/application/node_modules/@angular/core/src/type" but cannot be named.

The provider should be inside a module ? ... Someone has got an idea ?

Comment: There are lots of such patterns documented all across the web, including the Angular docs, which show examples of Angular modules to group together services. Before you do anything else, you're going to have to update your Angular knowledge and learn that you do not specify providers at the component level.

Comment: Sorry, but my example is based on Angular documentation : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#find-parent... As we can see in the example with "Alice Component", the provider is specified at the component level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My example was based on this [Angular example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#find-parent) and this [code](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/cb-dependency-injection/ts/eplnkr.html) (see parent-finder.component.ts).
To externalize the **helper method** to generate custom provider for each component, I had this code :

#### parent-finder.component.ts

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
...
// Marker class, used as an interface
export abstract class Parent { name: string; }
...
// Helper method to provide the current component instance in the name of a `parentType`.
// The `parentType` defaults to `Parent` when omitting the second parameter.
const provideParent =
      (component: any, parentType?: any) => {
         return { provide: parentType || Parent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => component) };
};
...
@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    ...
    providers:  [ provideParent(FooComponent) ]
})
export class FooComponent implements Parent
{
    name= 'Foo';
}
```

And I had to do this :

```
|- src/
   |- common/
      |- helpers/
          |- provider.helper.ts
          ...
|- components/
   |- foo.component.ts
   ...
```

### provider.helper.ts

```
//Old code
/*const provideParent = (component: any, parentType ? : any) => {
    return { provide: parentType || Parent, useExisting: forwardRef(() =>    component) };
};*/


// Right code
export function provideParent(component: any, parentType ? : any): Provider {
    let provider: Provider = { provide: parentType || Parent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => component) };
    return provider;
}
```

### foo.component.ts

```
import {provideParent} from '../common/helpers/provider.helper';
...
@Component({
   selector: 'foo',
   ...
   providers:  [ provideParent(FooComponent) ]
})
export class FooComponent implements Parent
{
    name= 'Foo';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Providers have to be specified at the module level. So if you have the structure:

```
|- src/
   |- common/
      |- providers/
         |- parent.provider.ts
         ... others providers   
   |- components/
      |- foo.component.ts 
      ... others components
```

You have to group your components into modules:

```
|- src/
   |- common/
      |- providers/
         |- parent.provider.ts
         ... others providers
   |- module1/
      |- foo.component.ts
      |- bar.component.ts
```

Then you can specify the providers for foo and bar in the module1 definition.

Comment: All my components are already in a module. I'm doing a library. I'm trying to use this [example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#find-parent). The problem is the helper method  "provideParent" and all components are in the same file in the demonstration [code](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/cb-dependency-injection/ts/eplnkr.html). I would like to externalize the **helper method** to use for all my components that they are in seperated files as well. I know to do this for components, directives, services, public functions but not for this case.